# Setting up mongo database locally

Tags: mongodb

I have a site hosted up on Heroku (a nodejs app), which is connected to my Mongo database. I was wondering if I can just set up a local mongo database rather than just connecting to the database (with the connection uri) everytime, just like SQL.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if your question is "can I setup a local mongo database", the answer appears to be yes, this is the first link that pops up when you type it into google :

https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/install/

Answer (score 0):

here is instruction on setting up mongo on Mac or Windows.

https://zellwk.com/blog/local-mongodb/.